# What does some syntax meaning in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the meaning and purpose of the syntactic sugar in this code?

```
def exp: Parser[Expr] = operands ~ binOp ~ exp ^^ {case  e1~o~e2=>BinaryOp(o,e1,e2)}
```

In particular, what do each of these expressions mean?

- `operands ~ binOp ~ exp ^^`
- `e1~o~e2`

Comment: Shouldn't you start with a beginner tutorial instead of a parser combinator when you just start learning Scala?

Comment: read http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html, but note it is chapter 31

Answer (score 3):

> operands ~ binOp ~ exp ^^ ...

Operators in scala are just ordinary method calls:

```
operands ~ binOp ~ exp ^^ ...
```

is the same as

```
operands.~(binOp).~(exp).^^(...)
```

You can see the documentation for the `~` and `^^` methods [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser), or you should be able to click through to them in your IDE.

> case e1~o~e2

This is matching a case class called `~` - lots of two-parameter things can be written in this "infix notation" in scala. It's equivalent to:

```
case ~(e1, ~(o, e2))
```

(see the documentation on [case classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html))

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Imm

Answer (score 1):

Those don't have any special meaning - they're just methods that are called `~` and `^^`. You'll need to look at the documentation/implementation of whichever library you're using that defined them to figure out what they do.